# Spring MVC POST Unsupporeted Media Type

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring-mvc, post

I receive 415 HTTP Unsupported Media Type error with the following code:

Spring MVC Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/addItem", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> addItem(@RequestBody final ToDoItem item) {
        toDoItemDao.create(item);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

JavaScript AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ToDoDemo.serverRoot + "/addItem",
    type:'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType:"json",
    data: JSON.stringify(oItem),
    success: function() {
    ...
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, strStatus, strErrorThrown) {
    ...
    }
});
```

pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

There are plenty of similar questions on StackOverflow I tried to use solutions from them, but none of the worked for me.
What am I missing?

Comment: If you specify `datatype:"json"`, you don't need your `headers`.

Comment: What Spring version are you using?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am using 3.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Removed headers according to your advice.

Comment: When you start up your application, in the logs, what request mapping is given to your handler above?

Comment: Actually I was wrong about the `datatype`. Add your headers back or use the `contentType` element. Also, `datatype` should be `dataType`.

Comment: I tried the demo (link on my answer bellow) with jackson 1.9.8 dependencies jackson-core-asl and jackson-mapper-asl (removing jackson-databind and jackson-core that don't exist for 1.9.8) and it works OK. Did you check if the header is scanned correctly, if the controller gets hit with the request, URL is correct?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Now it works without headers, so you were right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>`
```

to my Spring Context. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this answer for a working [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065047/how-we-can-pass-dojo-enhancedgrid-store-items-to-spring-mvc-controller-and-save/21149747#21149747) of an ajax JSON POST call to a spring MVC controller, returning a JSON response (uses Spring `3.2.1.RELEASE`).

With the chrome debugger tools or Firebub, make sure that the HTTP request contains:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

These two jackson jars are needed on the classpath, see the demo [pom.xml](https://bitbucket.org/mydevutils/dojo-spring-mvc-hello-world/src/6ff6b2ecf43d4edb4f2109d4c8ad3604b8839615/pom.xml?at=master):

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Make sure the `@Controller` is being [scanned correctly](https://bitbucket.org/mydevutils/dojo-spring-mvc-hello-world/src/6ff6b2ecf43d4edb4f2109d4c8ad3604b8839615/src/main/resources/spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml?at=master), it should say if it's initialized in the logs.

Comment: They are using an older version of Jackson which is also supported.